# Zero filled file on power cycle

Tags: windows, embedded

We are using Windows Embedded on an applicance and have found a problem with power cycling close to file creation: the file ends up full of zeros.

The process is to copy or create a file in a text editor. Shut the editor, if we used it. Do a hard power-cycle. The file is zero filled.

Is there a way of preventing this, so that we KNOW a file written to disk has actually been written?

Comment: Modify the program creating the log file to write the buffer to the file instead of writing to it when the application is closed.  What version of Windows embedded?  what application is creating the log file?

Comment: It is Windows Embedded 7. The application is writing to the file all the time, not just on close. The use of a text editor was to demonstrate that closing the file handle didn't guarantee the file was written.

Comment: If the program was writing the buffer continuously the device being turned off would not result in a zero filled file

Comment: If write caching is enabled in Windows, in the storage hardware driver, at the hardware level, etc., simply closing the file handle is **not** sufficient to guarantee the data was actually committed to storage. You must either disable all write caching mechanisms or frequently instruct anything that's doing caching to flush its buffers to storage.

Comment: Given closing a file flushes buffers, I can't see how flushing buffers will help. Any ideas about turning off caching?

Comment: You probably know more than I do about the effects of closing a file, but I'm doubtful that closing it is sufficient to flush *all* involved buffers. Regarding storage caching, have a look at the properties of your storage device in Device Manager. Also, have a look at [Sync](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897438.aspx) from Microsoft, a tool that forces Windows to flush its buffers.

Comment: Thanks, Twisty, that looks like a good tool. We'll play with that.